# Modify Java JTable AbstractTableModel from external data source (e.g. data read from a socket)

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I'm trying to modify TableDemo.java from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html so that the table model can be updated from an external data source (e.g. data read from a socket).  The only solution I could come up with involved changing the createAndShowGUI() method from static to non-static.  However, I do not know if this is the recommended solution for this use case.  My working code is pasted here, but I would appreciate any suggestions for improvement or alternate approaches.

```
package components;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DynamicTableDemo extends JPanel {

    // Add a MyTableModel member with a getter so you can modify table model data
    public final MyTableModel myTableModel;

    public DynamicTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        myTableModel = new MyTableModel();

        JTable table = new JTable(myTableModel);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public MyTableModel getMyTableModel() {
        return myTableModel;
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Stuff"};
        private Object[][] data = {
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)}
        };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * FIXME:
         * Multiple markers at this line
         * - overrides javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.getColumnClass
         * - Type safety: The return type Class for getColumnClass(int) from the type DynamicTableDemo.MyTableModel
         *   needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class<?> from the type AbstractTableModel
         * - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     * 
     * NOTE: Typically this is a static method but I removed static
     * so the underlying table model can be modified.
     */
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        this.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(this);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DynamicTableDemo dynamicTableDemo = new DynamicTableDemo();

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dynamicTableDemo.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

        int count = 0; // Change table data with an incrementing count
        while (true) {
            try {
                final int count2 = count; // Copy to a final variable for Runnable, feels a bit kludgey...
                /*
                 * In full application, blocking read of a value from a socket here.
                 * Note that myTableModel is updated from the EDT, but the socket read
                 * and sleep below will not be from the EDT.
                 */
                javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        dynamicTableDemo.getMyTableModel().setValueAt(new Integer(count2),
                                count2 % dynamicTableDemo.getMyTableModel().getRowCount(), 0);
                    }
                });
                count++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The logic to update the TableModel should be in the DynamicTableDemo class, not the main() method. All the main() method does is create and display the initial GUI. So instead of creating a while loop in the main() method, you would probably start a `SwingWorker (in the DynamicTableDemo class) to read data from the Socket, then you can "publish" the data at it is received. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks that have interim results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for a basic example.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I had skipped right to the tutorial on the Table component, but I should have also read the Concurrency in Swing tutorial as well.  I also need to brush up on inner classes and static nested classes, as I still don't fully understand the Swing examples.  Anyway, I'll posting my updated version for future reference, and in case anyone has further suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version based on comments:

```
package components;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DynamicTableDemo extends JPanel {

    // Make the JTable a field, so inner class TableCellTask can access it
    private final JTable table;
    
    public DynamicTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
        
        new TableCellTask().execute();
    }

    private static class TableCell {
        private final Object value;
        private final int row, col;
        TableCell(Object value, int row, int col) {
            this.value = value;
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }
    }

    private class TableCellTask extends SwingWorker<Void, TableCell> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            int count = 0; // Change table data with an incrementing count
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                /*
                 * In full application, blocking read of a value from a socket here.
                 * Note that myTableModel is updated from the EDT, but the socket read
                 * and sleep below will not be from the EDT.
                 */
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
                publish(new TableCell(count, count % table.getModel().getRowCount(), 0));
                count++;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<TableCell> tableCells) {
            for (TableCell tableCell : tableCells) {
                table.getModel().setValueAt(tableCell.value, tableCell.row, tableCell.col);
            }
        }
    }
    
    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Stuff"};
        private Object[][] data = {
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)},
                {new Integer(0)}
        };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     * 
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        DynamicTableDemo newContentPane = new DynamicTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

    }
}
```